# Ask to insert numbers in a string array, and repeat the question until the user has entered only numbers. Then make the array an integer "atoi()"

Tags: arrays, c, string, loops, fgets

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
char k[100]; //To input the numbers.

    printf("\nPlease, insert a number:\t");
    fgets(k,20,stdin); //Inserting the numbres

    int y=0;
    int i=0;
    do{//if any character loop.
        if (y!=0)
        {
            printf("\nPlease, insert a number:\t");
            fgets(k,20,stdin);
        }

        while (k[i]!='\n')
        {
            if (isdigit(k[i])==0) y++;
            printf("y=%d", y);
            i++;
        }

    //if (x>0) break;
    }while (y!=0);

    printf("\nk = %s\n",k); //Save key

    int w;
    atoi(k);
    w = atoi(k);
    printf("w = %d",w);
}
```

/*The problem relays when inserting characters, and going through the next runs.
//take full input from the user and check if the user has inputted digits only and then prompt the user to input the whole string again with digits only if there is any character on the array.
The idea is just to accept digits in the array.*/

Answer (score 0):

By now this works, the problem is that when you enter more than the array may accept it gives a strange loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
char k[100]; //To input the characters to code.

    int y;
    int i=0;
    do{
        printf("\nPlease, insert a number:\t");
        fgets(k,20,stdin);
        y=0;

        i=0;
        while (k[i]!='\n')
        {
            if (isdigit(k[i])==0) y++; //if not a digit.
            printf("y=%d", y);
            i++;
        }

        i=0;
        if (y>=1)
        {
            while (k[i]!='\0')
            {
                k[i]='\0';
                i++;
            }
        }

    //if (x>0) break;
    }while (y!=0);

    printf("\nk = %s\n",k); //Save key

    int w;
    atoi(k);
    w = atoi(k);
    printf("w = %d",w);
}
```